# I upgraded my Flutter project 2.5 to 2.10 But Now No one my Project is working. Why?

Tags: flutter

I upgraded my  Flutter project 2.5 to 2.10 But Now No one my Project is working. i don't know What is the Problem.

I have created a new project i am getting this error Even I am not Using PayPal Package

**

> ```
> Invalid depfile: E:\connnnnnnn\.dart_tool\flutter_build\978de1026cb7b90c4b8dd78f0d48d67b\kernel_snapshot.d
> Invalid depfile: E:\connnnnnnn\.dart_tool\flutter_build\978de1026cb7b90c4b8dd78f0d48d67b\kernel_snapshot.d
> Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'connevents' in 'package:connevents/paypal-Services/payPal-services.dart'.
> Error: Couldn't resolve the package 'webview_flutter' in 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart'.
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:1:8:
> ```
>
> Error: Not found:
> 'package:connevents/paypal-Services/payPal-services.dart'
> import 'package:connevents/paypal-Services/payPal-services.dart';
> ^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:3:8:
> Error: Not found: 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart'
> import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
> ^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:18:3:
> Error: Type 'PayPalServices' not found.
> PayPalServices services= PayPalServices();
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:58:16:
> Error: Type 'MethodChannel' not found.
> static const MethodChannel navigation = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:132:16: Error: Type 'MethodChannel' not found.
> static const MethodChannel platform = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:218:16: Error: Type 'MethodChannel' not found.
> static const MethodChannel textInput = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:243:16: Error: Type 'BasicMessageChannel' not found.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<Object?> keyEvent = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:243:16: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<Object?> keyEvent = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
> ^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:258:16: Error: Type 'BasicMessageChannel' not found.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<String?> lifecycle = BasicMessageChannel<String?>(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:258:16: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<String?> lifecycle = BasicMessageChannel<String?>(
> ^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:274:16: Error: Type 'BasicMessageChannel' not found.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<Object?> system = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:274:16: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<Object?> system = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
> ^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:286:16: Error: Type 'BasicMessageChannel' not found.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<Object?> accessibility = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:286:16: Error: Expected 0 type arguments.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<Object?> accessibility = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
> ^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:296:16: Error: Type 'MethodChannel' not found.
> static const MethodChannel platform_views = MethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:307:16: Error: Type 'MethodChannel' not found.
> static const MethodChannel skia = MethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:321:16: Error: Type 'MethodChannel' not found.
> static const MethodChannel mouseCursor = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:351:16: Error: Type 'MethodChannel' not found.
> static const MethodChannel restoration = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:376:16: Error: Type 'MethodChannel' not found.
> static const MethodChannel deferredComponent = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:391:16: Error: Type 'MethodChannel' not found.
> static const MethodChannel localization = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1439:26: Error: Type 'MethodChannel' not found.
> static void setChannel(MethodChannel newChannel) {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1530:8:
> Error: Type 'MethodChannel' not found.
> late MethodChannel _channel;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:58:43:
> Error: Method not found: 'OptionalMethodChannel'.
> static const MethodChannel navigation = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:132:41: Error: Method not found: 'OptionalMethodChannel'.
> static const MethodChannel platform = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:218:42: Error: Method not found: 'OptionalMethodChannel'.
> static const MethodChannel textInput = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:243:56: Error: Method not found: 'BasicMessageChannel'.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<Object?> keyEvent = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:258:57: Error: Method not found: 'BasicMessageChannel'.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<String?> lifecycle = BasicMessageChannel<String?>(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:274:54: Error: Method not found: 'BasicMessageChannel'.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<Object?> system = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:286:61: Error: Method not found: 'BasicMessageChannel'.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<Object?> accessibility = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:296:47: Error: Method not found: 'MethodChannel'.
> static const MethodChannel platform_views = MethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:307:37: Error: Method not found: 'MethodChannel'.
> static const MethodChannel skia = MethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:321:44: Error: Method not found: 'OptionalMethodChannel'.
> static const MethodChannel mouseCursor = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:351:44: Error: Method not found: 'OptionalMethodChannel'.
> static const MethodChannel restoration = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:376:50: Error: Method not found: 'OptionalMethodChannel'.
> static const MethodChannel deferredComponent = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:391:45: Error: Method not found: 'OptionalMethodChannel'.
> static const MethodChannel localization = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:18:3:
> Error: 'PayPalServices' isn't a type.
> PayPalServices services= PayPalServices();
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:18:28: Error: Method not found: 'PayPalServices'.
> PayPalServices services= PayPalServices();
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:31:
> Error: 'NavigationRequest' isn't a type.
> navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request){
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:153:14:
> Error: The method 'WebView' isn't defined for the class
> '_PayPalPaymentState'.
> - '_PayPalPaymentState' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
> ('/C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'WebView'.
> body: WebView(
> ^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart:155:26:
> Error: The getter 'JavascriptMode' isn't defined for the class
> '_PayPalPaymentState'.
> - '_PayPalPaymentState' is from 'package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart'
> ('/C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/platform_channel.dart').
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'JavascriptMode'.
> javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:58:16:
> Error: 'MethodChannel' isn't a type.
> static const MethodChannel navigation = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:132:16: Error: 'MethodChannel' isn't a type.
> static const MethodChannel platform = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:218:16: Error: 'MethodChannel' isn't a type.
> static const MethodChannel textInput = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:243:16: Error: 'BasicMessageChannel' isn't a type.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<Object?> keyEvent = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:258:16: Error: 'BasicMessageChannel' isn't a type.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<String?> lifecycle = BasicMessageChannel<String?>(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:274:16: Error: 'BasicMessageChannel' isn't a type.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<Object?> system = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:286:16: Error: 'BasicMessageChannel' isn't a type.
> static const BasicMessageChannel<Object?> accessibility = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:296:16: Error: 'MethodChannel' isn't a type.
> static const MethodChannel platform_views = MethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:307:16: Error: 'MethodChannel' isn't a type.
> static const MethodChannel skia = MethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:321:16: Error: 'MethodChannel' isn't a type.
> static const MethodChannel mouseCursor = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:351:16: Error: 'MethodChannel' isn't a type.
> static const MethodChannel restoration = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:376:16: Error: 'MethodChannel' isn't a type.
> static const MethodChannel deferredComponent = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/system_channels.dart:391:16: Error: 'MethodChannel' isn't a type.
> static const MethodChannel localization = OptionalMethodChannel(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1439:26: Error: 'MethodChannel' isn't a type.
> static void setChannel(MethodChannel newChannel) {
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/services/text_input.dart:1530:8:
> Error: 'MethodChannel' isn't a type.
> late MethodChannel _channel;
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/binding.dart:342:11: Error: 'MethodChannel' isn't a type.
> const MethodChannel methodChannel = MethodChannel('flutter/service_worker');
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> /C:/flutter_windows_2.10.4-stable/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/binding.dart:342:41: Error: Method not found: 'MethodChannel'.
> const MethodChannel methodChannel = MethodChannel('flutter/service_worker');
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> Unhandled exception:
> FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:package%3Aconnevents%2Fpaypal-Services%2FpayPal-services.dart;
> message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
> #0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:34:7)
> #1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:623:37)
> #2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:763:21)
>
> #3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:586:9)
>
> #4      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:85:12)

**

Comment: Have you tried `flutter clean && flutter pub get` on your project's dir ?

Comment: i have tried many time but did not work

Answer (score 0):

**1. android/app/build.gradle**

compileSdkVersion: 31 or higher
android {
compileSdkVersion 31

**2.** Go to File>ProjectStructure and Select the Android API 31 Platform

Answer (score 0):

Open Flutter Terminal run..

**flutter clean**

**flutter pub get**

[image]
build.gradle dependencies classpath upgrade

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem yesterday, i tired to run

git clean -xfd

git pull

flutter doctor

in cmd and i kept getting:

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

eventually i gave up and i deleted the old flutter sdk directory from my PC as well as the path from Enviroment Variables and i downloded the new sdk and setup flutter again and now it's running fine

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install